# Normal.dotm in a high security installation

Tags: vba, ms-word

Our company has a strict security policy regarding use of the C:\ drive.  In a nutshell, the user is not allowed to save any data there, user data should be on a network drive, period.  There are a few holes in this policy, such as saving temporary files, and writing to normal.dotm.

When it comes to Word, the Trust Center has **no entries under User Locations**.  C:\Users\VVKozlov\AppData\Roaming\ is simply not there, or elsewhere in the Trust Centre.

When it comes to Normal.dotx, it is saved in the default location of a typical Word installation, C:\Users\VVKozlov\AppData\Roaming\ which does not appear in the Trust Center.

Here is where this gets nasty: I have a Excel add-in which reads data from Word.  At the time Word is invoked, I receive the following familiar and irritating nag:

[image: Microsoft Word Security Notice]

Next, unless this dialogue box is **answered promptly**, I receive the following error message:

Run-time error '429':

ActiveX component can't create object

At this time, the add-in is effectively broken and needs to be restarted.

Is there a workaround to this security problem?  One thing which looks promising is to save a shortcut in C:\Users\VVKozlov\AppData\Roaming\ which points to a file which is in one of the Policy Locations in the trust centre.

Comment: Could Normal.dotm be digitally signed and that signature (Publisher) trusted? Then you could set macros to enable if digitally signed. Also, have you checked whether it's possible to suppress the message for this single file with a network/group policy? That's off-topic for Stack Overflow, but there a people in the Microsoft TechNet forum that may know how to do that. You could also try "shelling" the Word application with a command line switch that loads it with the installation defaults (no Normal.dotm).

Comment: Otherwise, perhaps do the document manipulation via the Open XML file format, which is done on the closed file (not open in the Word environment).

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your comments.  At the moment, the user accepts a solution where immediately prior to invoking Word, a dialog box to the effect of "Please answer the next dialogue box promptly!" is shown.  I was thinking also of making this application a Word application which invokes Excel instead of the other way around as it is now.  Network and group policy is largely not negotiable here.

Comment: @CindyMeister I've done a lot with manipulating the XML of late and am happy to say that I have not yet made changes resulting in an unreadable Word document.  Automating 7-zip has worked well so far.

Comment: @CindyMeister Also the shortcut idea does not work at all.  Word promptly writes a new Normal.dotm alongside the shortcut.  Thanks for the Microsoft TechNet suggestion.